How to use fileupload2 with Tomcat 10?
I'm upgrading a Tomcat project from Tomcat 9 to 10, which means I'm now using the Servlet 5 packages (jakarta.servlet instead of java.servlet). My project needs apache fileupload, so I updated it to fileupload2 (org.apache.commons:commons-fileupload2). The problem is that my source code cannot find anything in the 'org.apache.commons.fileupload2' package, it just says 'cannot resolve symbol'. Is the package name different? What else could be wrong?

If your project uses a different version of Java than what is configured in your IDE or build tool, it might cause class path issues leading to the "cannot resolve symbol" error.
Please verify the SDK version in your project settings.
